# Disk Partitioning and Layout with LVM

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, lvm, partition

I am trying to determine the best disk configuration/disk layout/partitioning scheme for a large, virtualized, multi tenanted environment.

Our current scheme is very similar to rhel/centos defaults, which can be a little inflexible when it comes to adding space to the root lvm volume.

Example current deployment below:

```
[root@server ~]# lsblk 
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0 19.8G  0 part 
  ├─vg0-lv0 (dm-0) 253:0    0    2G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg0-lv1 (dm-1) 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg0-lv2 (dm-3) 253:3    0    4G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─vg0-lv3 (dm-4) 253:4    0    4G  0 lvm  /home
  └─vg0-lv4 (dm-5) 253:5    0    4G  0 lvm  /usr
sdb                  8:16   0  100G  0 disk 
└─vg1-lv0 (dm-2)   253:2    0   95G  0 lvm  /u01
[root@server ~]#
```

Im thinking that something similar to following will be more suitable and give us the flexibility we are looking for:

```
[root@server ~]# lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                  11:0    1  362M  0 rom  
vda                 252:0    0    1G  0 disk 
└─vda1              252:1    0 1023M  0 part /boot
vdb                 252:16   0   20G  0 disk 
├─vg_system-lv_swap 253:0    0    1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
├─vg_system-lv_usr  253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  /usr
├─vg_system-lv_root 253:2    0   10G  0 lvm  /
├─vg_system-lv_var  253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /var
└─vg_system-lv_home 253:4    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
vdc                  8:16   0  100G  0 disk 
└─vg_u01            254:0    0   95G  0 lvm  /u01
[root@server ~]#
```

Is there anything glaringly wrong with this this configuration?

Can anyone think of any reason why this would not be a good idea?

I understand that adding a new physical volume to an existing volume group is easy, however this allows us to maintain consistency and reduce complexity - in that sda1 will always be /boot, disk 2 will always be system etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you going to use kvm to  made a large, virtualized, multi tenanted environment, I would recommend you to allocate more space for tmp, because when you run snapshot VM it will l[ocate temporary files on that directory](http://blog.nielshorn.net/2011/03/qemu-snapshots-temporary-files-where-they-go-and-how-to-change-that/).

And also why you don't using RAID?

Comment: i may not have explained myself clearly - the sizes in the examples are irrelevant. the core of my question revolves around the disk layout - eg: a small disk for /boot and then "pure" lvm on the second larger disk which will allow for a some flexibility with growing disks quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In practical terms I don't see any difference. I like lvm because of the flexibility too, and both scenarios looks good for me.